# How to create a genome-wide reads density map in R (for a bacterial genome)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bioinformatics

I have a data frame (pLog) containing the number of reads per nucleotide for a chip-seq experiment done for a E. coli genome (4.6MB). I want to be able to plot on the X axis the chromosomal position and on the Y axis the number of reads. To make it easier, I binned the data in windows of 100bp. That makes the data frame of 46,259 rows and 2 columns. One column is named "position" and has a number representing a chromosomal position (1,101,201,....) and the other column is named "values" and contains the number of reads found on that bin e.g.(210,511,315,....). I have been using ggplot for all my analysis and I would like to use it for this plot, if possible.

I am trying for the graph to look something like this:
[image]

but I haven't been able to plot it.

This is how my data looks like

[image]

I tried

```
ggplot(pLog,aes(position))+ 
geom_histogram(binwidth=50)
ggsave(file.jpg)
```

And this is how it looks like :(

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by you "haven't been able to plot anything similar"? I mean surely you have tried a line plot and it doesn't work?

Comment: I also don't understand what the difficulty is with ggplot. What doesn't it do? Could you share the code for an attempt plus (if it renders) an image of the plot so we might see what is wrong with it. Or maybe a snippet of data by posting the output of `dput(head(your_data))`?

Comment: @StupidWolf I edit my question to include what you asked for. Hope you can help me make sense of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use geom_histogram(), try geom_line:

```
pLog=data.frame(position=seq(1,100000,by=100),
value=rnbinom(10000,mu=100,size=20))
ggplot(pLog,aes(x=position,y=value))+geom_line(alpha=0.7,col="steelblue")
```

[image]

Most likely you need to play around to get the visualization you need